Docker image has old library after upgrade base image
My Dockerfile based on php:8.2-fpm-alpine3.17. Recently, Amazon Inspector found out  a vulnerability CVE-2023-49468 in my image, in libde265 (version 1.0.12-r0). I checked that vulnerability was fixed in libde265 (version 1.0.15-r0) here. I checked libde265 package on the official site alpine and realised that alpine 3.17 already use libde265 (version 1.0.15-r0).
Why when I re-build my docker image via docker build --no-cache command my image is still has libde265 (version 1.0.12-r0.X86_64) so I can't fix vulnerability ?
Alpine 3.17 is still supported for security fixes until 2024-11-22, is it correct that will be release after this date and my image pull new base image automatically and the vulnerability will disappear ?

I'm not sure libde265 is natively packaged with php:8.2-fpm-alpine3.17 or alpine:3.17. Because when I do docker run -it --rm php:8.2-fpm-alpine3.17 /bin/sh  and then apk add libde265 it installs libde265 (1.0.15-r0).

@MartinTovmassian In this case why I see libde265 (version 1.0.15-r0) on official site (link below in quetsion) ?

this Alpine packages list seems more like the list of available packages rather than the default ones. Maybe I'm wrong regarding the OS image but regarding the Docker image I'm pretty sure that it does not come with all these packages.

I have a hierarchy of images (one is inherited by the other). It was necessary to update each of the parent images using the command docker build --no-cache
